# Looking for help with dependent jointly normal/Gaussian RVs!

Tags: probability-theory

Firstly, if two jointly Gaussian random variable (X and Y) both have means 0 and variance 1, with a correlation coefficient of -0.5, then they MUST be dependent, correct?

If the above is true, and A and B are sums and differences of random variables X and Y (i.e. A = X + Y), then how can one prove if A and B are *also* jointly Gaussian/normal? A lot of the theorems I found *only* apply to independent jointly normal RVs, so I do not know where to begin if X and Y are dependent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is yes, they are dependent as jointly Gaussian random variables are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated.

For the second question I'll address something more general:

Suppose $X$ of size $k$ follows a jointly random distribution $\mathcal{N} \left( \mu, \Sigma \right)$; then the joint density function of $X$ is given by $$f_{X}(x) = \left(2 \pi\right)^{-\frac{k}{2}} \lvert \Sigma \rvert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{exp} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x - \mu\right)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \left(x - \mu\right)\right).$$ Let $Y = A X + b$ where $A$ is an invertible matrix. Then $X = A^{-1} Y - A^{-1}b$. It is easy to see that the Jacobian matrix is given by $J \left(Y\right) = \left( A^{-1} \right)^{T}$. Then the joint density function for $Y$ would be 
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_{Y}(y) & = & \mathrm{abs} \left( \lvert J \left(y\right)\rvert \right) f_{X} \left(x\left(y\right)\right) \\
& = & \left(\lvert \left( A^{-1}\right)^{T} \rvert^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(2 \pi\right)^{-\frac{k}{2}} \lvert \Sigma \rvert^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{exp} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(A^{-1}\left(y - b\right) - \mu\right)^{T} \Sigma^{-1} \left(A^{-1} \left(y - b\right) - \mu\right)\right)
\end{array}.
$$ 
Using the fact that for any matrices $A$ and $B$, with $A$ invertible is true that $\lvert A^{T} \rvert = \lvert A \rvert$, $\lvert A^{-1} \rvert = \lvert A \rvert^{-1}$ and $\lvert A B \rvert = \lvert A \rvert \lvert B \rvert$ it follows that
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
f_{Y}(y) & = & \left( 2 \pi \right)^{-\frac{k}{2}} \lvert A \Sigma A^{T} \rvert^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{exp} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \left( y - A \mu - b \right)^{T} \left( A^{T} \right)^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}A^{-1} \left( y - A \mu - b\right) \right)\\
& = & \left( 2 \pi \right)^{-\frac{k}{2}} \lvert A \Sigma A^{T} \rvert^{-\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{exp} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \left( y - A \mu - b \right)^{T} \left( A \Sigma A^{T} \right)^{-1} \left( y - A \mu - b\right) \right).
\end{array}
$$
Therefore $Y$ also follows a jointly Gaussian distribution with mean $A \mu + b$ and variance-covariance matrix $A \Sigma A^{T}$. This is, if $Y$ is an invertible linear transformation of $X$ and $X$ follows a jointly Gaussian distribution then $Y$ also follows a jointly Gaussian distribution.

For your question, in matrix notation $A = X + Y$ and $B = X - Y$ is represented by
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{r} A \\ B \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{rr} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{r} X \\ Y \end{array} \right].
$$
The given matrix is invertible so $A$ and $B$ are also jointly Gaussian.